# How to find $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^2\ln x$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't find the limit of $x^2 \ln x$ as $x$ approaches $0$. I can use only notable special limits and I'm not allowed to use l'Hopital's method.

Comment: You need to specify which definition of $ln(x)$ you use (or which special limits involving $ln(x)$ that are OK).

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x$ with $e^{-t}$, so $x\to 0^+$ turns into $t\to +\infty$:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^2\ln x =- \lim_{t\to+\infty}(e^{-t})^2t.$$
Now either you already know that the exponential "always wins" against polynomials, or you use the inequality $e^x\ge 1+x$ for the exponential and note that for $t>0$
$$0<(e^{-t})^2t=\frac t{(e^t)^2}\le\frac t{(1+t)^2}<\frac1t.$$

Answer (score 0):

take $y := \frac{1}{x}$, then $y \rightarrow \infty$ and use the fact that $-\ln(x) = \ln(y)$ and $\frac{\ln y }{y} \rightarrow 0$. note that you have $| x^2 \ln(x)|$ = $\frac{\ln y}{y^2}$